# onOffsetsChanged: move Bitmap

Tags: java, android, live-wallpaper, android-canvas

i want my Bitmap that has the height of the screen and has a bigger width than the screen to be moved a little bit to the right or left if the user changes the desktop so he can see the entire image.

Here is my code that just works partially:

```
        int x = -1*(int)((xOffset*bmp.getWidth()));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x, 0, null);
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get exact pixel values via the variables xPixels and yPixels in onOffsetsChanged().  See my answer here: [android live wallpaper rescaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208203/android-live-wallpaper-rescaling/5347525#5347525)

For example, in onOffsetsChanged(), you can set a private class variable

```
mPixels = xPixels;
```

Then, in your draw routine

```
holder = getSurfaceHolder();
c = holder.lockCanvas();
c.translate(mPixels, 0f);
// c.drawBitmap ... goes here :-)
```

Typically, you will want a bitmap twice the width of your screen, with your artwork centered in the middle.  For example: 320 pixel width screen -> 640 pixel width bitmap with "center" from 160 to 480.  mPixels will be 0 at the left most launcher screen (of 5), -160 at the center, and -320 at the rightmost screen.

Comment: no, it didnt work, when i go to the last screen there is still some black room...

Comment: @nomoral I can only guess that you're making a subtle mistake...bitmap too small, wrong density, etc.  Without being able to see your code, I can only suggest that you find an open source example that works, and compare it to what you have done.

Comment: @nomoral  Yes, using xStep, xOffset, and getDesiredMinimumWidth, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208203/android-live-wallpaper-rescaling/5347525

Comment: ahh, i just cant put the pieces together. what must i exactly do with  xStep, xOffset, and getDesiredMinimumWidth to get the correct x value for canvas.drawBitmap?

Comment: @nomoral This is tricky stuff -- hard to get right without our friend Eclipse.  I have expanded my answer above to show how I typically do  things ... use xPixels to translate the canvas before drawing.  You could compute xPixels manually, but you'd get the same result.