# Android live wallpaper based on the current wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I'm trying to create a live wallpaper which uses the current device wallpaper as its background.

You can see a good example of it in the 'Bubbles' live wallpaper, which does exactly what I need.

I have tried using transparent canvas but no luck.

Any idea / reference / sample would be much apprichiated.

Thanks a lot,

E.

Answer (score 3):

You can try using the [WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) to get the current wallpaper, save it to a file and them use it as a background on your live wallpaper. Not sure this is gonna work though.

Comment: I like this idea (transparent canvas cannot work--you must use the supplied canvas).  Maybe use peekDrawable() to get the wp's drawable and then .draw(c) where c is the canvas you get by locking the surface holder?

Comment: Thanks for your input.
I've tried this approach but the problem is that I get a drawable for the all wallpaper rather than the current frame the user is currently seeing. Any ideas how to get the current frame?

Comment: Can't you recreate the frames when the user scrolls through his home screens? This way, you just need the Drawable for the whole walpaper.

Comment: How can I do it? do you have any example or a reference?

Comment: @Erez Try saving xPixels in xOffsetsChanged and translating your canvas.  See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573451/onoffsetschanged-move-bitmap/6574649