# strange behaviour of live wallpaper in preview

Tags: android, andengine, live-wallpaper, game-physics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android live wallpaper rescaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208203/android-live-wallpaper-rescaling)
>   [AndEngine Live wallpaper preview Bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872613/andengine-live-wallpaper-preview-bug)

I am developing a live wallpaper using AndEngine. The problem is when i preview th wallpaper in portrait mode it works fine, but when rotate the wallpaper to landscape mode the wallpaper becomes weird. Worse, being in portrait mode when I set the wallpaper and after going to home screen I rotate the tablet to landscape mode it works fine.

Here is the `onConfigurationChanged()` function code.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig){
if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        mScene.setScale(1);
        mScene.setPosition(mSceneX,mSceneY);
        //scene.setBackground(sb);
    }
    else if(newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        Log.d("conf", "conf");
        mSceneX=mScene.getX();
        mSceneY=mScene.getY();
        mScene.setScaleY(1330f/790f);
        mScene.setScaleX(790f/1330f);

        mScene.setPosition(mScene.getX()+getX(160f),mScene.getY()-getY(420));
        //scene.setBackground(sb2);
    }
}
```