# Create Android Live Wallpaper for any resolution

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, screen-resolution

I'm a new Android developer, and I am creating android Live Wallpaper as the first project. How can I support multi resolution?
I don't know whether I should scale images by code or change them according to resolution.

Comment: Go through all three of the pages listed [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html), and follow their advice.

Comment: Yes,I've done but I need to know is there anything special for live wallpapers,I set an image in background and change it automatically like a gif file.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I'm a new Android developer too, but recently I saw a nice tutorial about Live WallPapers on Android that may be help you and in addition I found a similar question here in SO.

- [Android Live Wallpaper - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html)
- [SO: Android live wallpaper rescaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208203/android-live-wallpaper-rescaling)